# Удаление объекта в java

Tags: java, swing

У меня есть двумерный массив объектов:

```
Figure[][] pFigure = new Figure[49][49];
```

Класс `Figure` реализует рисование прямоугольника на форме.

Вопрос, как реализовать удаление объекта `Figure`, и что бы с формы он тоже удалялся.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Figure extends JComponent {

    private Color color;

    // параметры: цвет
    Figure(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    public void settColor(boolean a) {
        if (a)
            this.color = Color.YELLOW;
        else
            this.color = Color.GREEN;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // прорисовка фигуры
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 9, 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете добавить код где реализовали `Figure`?

Comment: @AsadGaniev, добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Самый хороший и пожалуй и правильный вариант это перерисовать graphics каждый раз когда меняется содержимое двумерного массива `Figure`. То есть Вам надо будет создать класс который будет управлять этим массивом типа `FigureManager`.

Хотя использование массива на мой взгляд является не оптимальным вариантом. Лучше использовать Java Collections.

Comment: Если я сделаю двумерный `ArrayList`, то через `remove()` объект будет удаляться?

Comment: @ArtemAndriukov Почему вы хотите сделать это именно в двумерном массиве?